# react-native 0.59 migrated to API 29 how to request permission on location

Tags: react-native

I'm using rn 0.59.
Currently on Android API 28, when you request a permission,
It has an option for 'Allow all the time'

But when I shifted to API 29.
It is gone on the permission box.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

```
export async function requestLocationPermission() {
    try {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            return PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED;
        } else if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.NEVER_ASK_AGAIN) {
            return PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.NEVER_ASK_AGAIN;
        } else {
            return PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.DENIED;
        }
    } catch (err) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

how can you access the background location here, since it has only ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a bridge on android

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getReactApplicationContext(),
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION);


if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    promise.resolve(true);
} else {

    final Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
    
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
        activity,
        new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        },
        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION
    );
    
    promise.resolve(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#request-background-location

> On Android 11 (API level 30) and higher, however, the system dialog doesn't include the Allow all the time option. Instead, users must enable background location on a settings page.
>
> You can help users navigate to this settings page by following best practices when requesting the background location permission. The process for granting the permission depends on your app's target SDK version.

Open settings using the same permissions library that you're using :

https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions#opensettings

```js
import {openSettings} from 'react-native-permissions';

openSettings().catch(() => console.warn('cannot open settings'));
```

Comment: This only supports the updated version. The latest version is not compatible with RN 0.59

Comment: look at the native code which is mapped to `openSettings()` (they are one liners on both platforms). you can make a custom module that does just this